# How can I wait to start a container only when the exit code of another is throw?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm creating a way to configure a development environment for new developers that join the company. Actually I had created a docker-compose file and inside of this I had 2 services (git and maven), I need to wait for git to get the code from repository and after that run the maven build.

All solutions that I found are very complicated and complex and from my perspective, it should not be in this way because is a very simple thing.

I tried to put inside of maven service something like this

command: `docker wait git-clone command: mvn clean install`

But this didn't work, I now have this command waiting inside of docker to wait a container exit but it didn't work very well, the mvn clean install don't wait for the previous command.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

As in your design, the first service will pull the code, while the second container will use this code to build. So I guess you have volume between the 2 services to share the sourcecode.

Then, one workable solution could be next steps:

1) `git service` to pull the code
2) `git service` to put a flag file after pull the code, like `touch done.txt` in volume
3) `mvn service` loop to see if `done.txt` in this volume, if not, continue sleep some time & loop again
4) `mvn service` find the `done.txt` already in this volume, then start to build

---

But if as you said, if you think it's too complex, then a workaround way could be start the service one by one in a shell script, a sample as next:

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: '3'
services:
  frontend:
    image: alpine
    command: "sleep 30"
  backend:
    image: alpine
    command: "ls"
```

**start.sh:**

```
#!/bin/bash

docker-compose up frontend
docker-compose up backend
```

Then, the shell script will first start the service `frontend`, only after the first service finish, then the second service `backend` will start, execution like next(Here, frontend is your git service while backend you could treat it as your mvn service, just an example):

```
$ ./start.sh
Starting 77_frontend_1 ... done
Attaching to 77_frontend_1
77_frontend_1 exited with code 0
Starting 77_backend_1 ... done
Attaching to 77_backend_1
backend_1   | bin
backend_1   | dev
backend_1   | etc
backend_1   | home
backend_1   | lib
backend_1   | media
backend_1   | mnt
backend_1   | opt
backend_1   | proc
backend_1   | root
backend_1   | run
backend_1   | sbin
backend_1   | srv
backend_1   | sys
backend_1   | tmp
backend_1   | usr
backend_1   | var
77_backend_1 exited with code 0
```